# Websocket Connection Error - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, database, websocket, xampp

I am building a simple chat tool in php and websocket is one of the best way for chat applications

I am a completely beginner in websocket i wrote a simple code for websocket connection but got an error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/htdocs/chat.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Here is the full code i have written so far

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function showMessage(messageHTML) {
        $('#chat-box').append(messageHTML);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/htdocs/chat.php"); 
        websocket.onopen = function(event) { 
            showMessage("<div class='chat-connection-ack'>Connection is established!</div>");       
        }
        websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
            var Data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            showMessage("<div class='"+Data.message_type+"'>"+Data.message+"</div>");
            $('#chat-message').val('');
        };

        websocket.onerror = function(event){
            showMessage("<div class='error'>Problem due to some Error</div>");
            console.log(event.data);
        };
        websocket.onclose = function(event){
            showMessage("<div class='chat-connection-ack'>Connection Closed</div>");
        }; 
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chat-box">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I checked in my php.ini file the websocket is not comment out

Comment: First of all, PHP is not a suitable programming language for developing a WebSocket based application! But if you insist on using it, check this library:
http://socketo.me/

Comment: In my opinion, php is not the preferred tool when working with Websockets. There are libraries as amphp (https://github.com/amphp) implementing Websockets with php. But most hoster won't allow to execute php scripts that won't stop running

Comment: What is i do not want to use any external library is there any solution to my problem

Comment: Either you write it yourself (but implementing the websocket protocol is not this easy) or you work with good old ajax requests

Comment: Putting personal opinions aside, PHP provides a paradigm that works just fine for websockets. I realize you don't want to use a library, but I recommend [Rachet](http://socketo.me) as Hamid points out.

Comment: Do i really need to use any library or can i write this on my own?

Comment: You can write it on your own...sure. But you'll eventually end up writing, testing, validating, etc. a library that someone else already has written, tested, validated, etc. Your choice.

Comment: and as I already said - if you want to host your chat anywhere it'll be hard to find a host where you can use websockets. I think, this is the biggest problem with websockets in php

Comment: @kuh-chan i can't understand your last comment, I will live this project on shared hosting

Comment: I read many tutorials on websocket without any library i think they are using very simple code I guess

Comment: I think here are some tutorials where they directly implement websockets please see this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications and this http://www.abrandao.com/2013/06/websockets-html5-php/

Comment: And this also https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket kindly check

Comment: the first link: just the websocket calls with javascript. this part is easy.
the other links are telling you that you have to run your script as deamon. And that's the point I'm talking about - not all shared hosters allow this. and the codes these tutorials provide don't use the advantages of websocket. To do so you'll have to read some stuff about async communication with php; a good resource is: https://nikic.github.io/2012/12/22/Cooperative-multitasking-using-coroutines-in-PHP.html

Comment: So as per everyone recommendation i have to use some library for a good and easy implementation of websocket

Comment: Is there any way to solve this issue in this condition

Comment: Anyone here to solve this particular issue. Any help will be really appreciated